# Trajectory question

Tags: classical-mechanics

With initial conditions $ x(0)= l > 0 $ and $\dot{x}(0)=0$ ,determine the trajectory $x(t)$ of the particle.  Also determine its position and velocity at times $$\frac {1}{2}T,\frac {1}{3}T,\frac {1}{4}T$$

Where $$x(t)=a\cos(t\sqrt{k})$$
$$\frac {d^2x}{dt^2} + kx = 0$$  the period $$T=\frac {2\pi}{\sqrt{k}}$$ (I don't know if this is needed)

This is a part of a question and these are all the things I believe are needed

Comment: just plug in those values in x(t) and see what you get.

Comment: @Chloe Williams-- have you attempted the problem yourself?